# How do I connect to an SSH server from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

I've been given this information (changed to protect the innocent):

```
Hostname: secret_server.homeserver.org
Port: 4033
Username: user
Password: $ecrectP#ras3
Protocol: scp
```

I don't have to have a nice GUI. What's the key to connecting to this server? I understand that SCP will copy files from a source directory to my target directory (both ways).  How can I connect via SSH to this server so I can traverse the directories and find the files I need?

the following terminal command just times out:

```
ssh -p 4033 user@secret_server.homeserver.org
```

is it me or the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the connection just times out, there may be some network problem. For example, some firewall blocks the connection.

Can you ping the server?

```
ping secret_server.homeserver.org
```

In addition, ssh connection may be blocked, and only file copying with scp is allowed.

Does it work if you use scp to copy files?

Comment: received an email just this morning of the server being down. :)

Answer (score 5):

> Protocol: scp

It's possible that they've enabled only scp, and that ssh remains disabled.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't get in using ssh, sftp still might be an option.  It's not a full shell but at least you can traverse directories, list files and transfer them.

```
sftp -oPort=4033 user@secret_server.homeserver.org:/path_to_destination/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scp -p 4033 file_to_copy user@secret_server.homeserver.org:/path_to_destination/
```

Comment: right... but what about connecting via SSH?

Comment: Your original command looks correct.  You many not have rights to a shell on the server.

Comment: if that's the case will I have to do an ssh-keygen? or something like that?

Comment: If that's the case, you'll have to contact the server's administrators and have them give you access.